# using a user defined bash function in xargs

Tags: bash, xargs

I have this self-defined function in my .bashrc :

```
function ord() {
  printf '%d' "'$1"
}
```

How do I get this function to be used with xargs ?:

```
cat anyFile.txt | awk '{split($0,a,""); for (i=1; i<=100; i++) print a[i]}' | xargs -i ord {}
xargs: ord: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Maybe for the UUOC? I am not the downvoter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, your function only uses 1 argument, so using xargs here will only take the first arg. You need to change the function to the following:

```
ord() {
   printf '%d' "$@"
}
```

To get xargs to use a function from your bashrc, you must spawn a new interactive shell. Something like this may work:

```
awk '{split($0,a,""); for (i=1; i<=100; i++) print a[i]}' anyFile.txt | xargs bash -i -c 'ord $@' _
```

Since you are already depending on word splitting, you could just store awk's output in an array.

```
arr=(awk '{split($0,a,""); for (i=1; i<=100; i++) print a[i]}' anyFile.txt)
ord "${arr[@]}"
```

Or, you can use awk's printf:

```
awk '{split($0,a,""); for (i=1; i<=100; i++) printf("%d",a[i])}' anyFile.txt
```

Comment: For the all awk solution it doesn't convert correctly.  Numbers are printed as their digits, while letters are converted to '0'.  I'm looking to convert ASCII values to integers.

Comment: Or you can export the function (`export -f`) and *not* make the shell interactive.

Answer (score 0):

In the trivial case, you can use `/usr/bin/printf`:

```
xargs -I {} /usr/bin/printf '%d' "'{}"
```